Issue with Schema Validation in Kafka using PySpark Structured Streaming
I am trying to produce Avro-encoded messages to Kafka using PySpark Structured Streaming. My schema is registered in the Confluent Schema Registry. However, I encounter an InvalidRecordException when the schema validation is turned on.
Code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, col
from pyspark.sql.avro.functions import to_avro
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

# Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("KafkaAvroSchemaProducer") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Define the schema for the DataFrame
schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True)
])

# Define sample message
sample_message = {"name": "John"}

# Create DataFrame with the sample message
sample_df = spark.createDataFrame([sample_message], schema=schema)

# Convert DataFrame to Avro format
avro_df = sample_df.select(
    to_avro(struct("*")).alias("value")  # Convert to Avro format
).selectExpr("CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS key", "value")

# Kafka producer configuration
producer_config = {
    'kafka.bootstrap.servers': 'your_kafka_broker:9092',
    'topic': 'sample_topic',
    'schema.registry.url': 'http://your_schema_registry:8081'
}

# Write DataFrame to Kafka in Avro format
avro_df.write \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", producer_config['kafka.bootstrap.servers']) \
    .option("topic", producer_config['topic']) \
    .option("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer") \
    .option("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer") \
    .option("schema.registry.url", producer_config['schema.registry.url']) \
    .save()

# Stop the Spark session
spark.stop()

Schema from Schema Registry:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "User",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "name", "type": "string"}
  ]
}

Exception:
InvalidRecordException: The record is rejected by the record interceptor

Is there something wrong with how I'm serializing the data to Avro format using to_avro? Is there any additional configuration needed for schema validation to pass?

The builtin to_avro function doesn't create schema registry compatible message

@OneCricketeer I also tried with a json schema and to_json method. It failed with a message saying rejected by broker when the schema validation was on.

How did you resolve it @yAsH?
